# "Catch" all messages that was sent via SendMessage method

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I'm using `SendMessage` method (WinAPI) to pass messages between 4 applications.
I want to create another application, calling LogApplication, that using like a log application, meaning that any message was sent from application to application via `SendMessage` insert into a log file.
I can to "catch" all the messages that send even if the 4 applications isn't send the message to LogApplication? i can catch all the messages that sent via `SendMessage` method?
If so, how?
Thanks.


`SendMessage`:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: It's what WinSpy++ does...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti, i know... but how i can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what [Hooks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632589(v=vs.85).aspx) are for. You install it with the use of [SetWindowsHookEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx), `WH_GETMESSAGE` should be fine for you. You will find examples in those SO:

[Global hook using WH_GETMESSAGE and WH_KEYBOARD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26869973/global-hook-using-wh-getmessage-and-wh-keyboard)

[WH_GETMESSAGE global hook not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209475/wh-getmessage-global-hook-not-working)